# Angular 6 setTimeout and clearTimeout error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

I have an angular 6 strange problem.

I am using setTimeout and clearTimeout functions to start/cancel the timeout.
However this sometimes works, and sometimes doesn't.
Even if the user triggers an (click) event and the clearTimeout is run, sometimes it forces player to draw two cards.

Here is the code

```
//an event that says we must call uno 
this._hubService.mustCallUno.subscribe(() => {
      this.mustCallUno = true;
      this._interval = window.setInterval(() => {
        this.countdown -= 100;
      }, 100);
      this._timer = window.setTimeout(() => {
        if (this.mustCallUno) {
            this.drawCard(2);
            this.callUno();
        }
      }, 2000);
    });

// a function player calls from UI to call uno and not draw 2 cards
  callUno() {
    this.mustCallUno = false;
    window.clearTimeout(this._timer);
    window.clearInterval(this._interval);
    this.countdown = 2000;
  }
```

So even if the player calls callUno() function, the setTimeout is executed. Even worse, the code goes through the first if check inside the setTimeout `if( this.mustCallUno)` which by all means should be false since we just set it to false when we called callUno() function `this.mustCallUno = false;`.

I used setTimeout (returns NodeJS.Timer) before window.setTimeout and the result was the same.

Comment: May I ask why aren't you using rxjs observables ?

Comment: @Florian i'm kinda new to all this angular and rxjs world. Can you post the solution with observable and link me to some useful "Getting Started" page? Many thanks

Comment: can you share the full code! I can't really understand what you are intending to do here

Comment: @tonymarkoc oki. I'll show you a stackblitz with rxjs solution and documentation page.

Comment: @Aravind The rest of the code is really not relevant. We get an event through websocket that the player must call uno (first function I wrote above - subscribe), and then the user has 2 seconds to press the UNO button in the UI which will call `callUno()` function which was supposed to clear timeout, so that the player doesn't draw 2 cards.

Comment: why you need setInterval, you are not even doing anything with "countdown"

Comment: @yanky_cranky it's just for UI purpose, to show the user how much time he has left to press the button, kinda like a countdown. So in the html i have {{countdown}}. You can ignore that part of the code for this issue.

Comment: try to log some value inside subscribe method and see, if subscriber been called multiple times, when you get drawCard even after clearinterval. This is the most promising test case for this scenario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using angular6+, so I suggest you to use reactive programming library such as [rxjs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/)

I made you a small example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aq1b34).

Comment: Hi. The problem was that i was never unsubscribing from the observables. Your answer helped me realize this,  so i will mark it as correct.

Comment: Glad that it helped you !

Answer (score 1):

Check for the possibility where function in `this._hubService.mustCallUno.subscribe` is run twice or multiple times, usually initially which you might not be expecting. Put a logger in function passed to `mustCallUno.subscribe` and `callUno`.

In this case what might be happening is `this._timer` and `this._interval` will have a different reference while the old references they hold, were not cleared because `callUno` is not called or is called less number of times than the callback in subscribe.

Comment: I tried also adding    `window.clearTimeout(this._timer);
    window.clearInterval(this._interval); ` as the first two lines in the subscribe method, no effect.

Comment: Yes but it is in `callUno` right? Is it guaranteed that `callUno` will be called before callback to subscribe is called the next time?

Comment: It doesn't look like a good architecture, but putting a simple logger should verify it.